# Is Maeby adopted?

Tags: arrested-development

In season one episode 12 - "Martha Complex" - Tobias mentions that he and Lindsay were unable to conceive, yet they have a daughter - Maeby. Since Tobias and Lindsay were apparently unable to conceive, does this mean that Maeby is adopted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All is revealed in the next episode, "Beef Consommé".  George Michael wonders about Maeby's paternity, and is told by Lucille that the family spent $130,000 in fertility treatments that eventually enabled Lindsay to conceive Maeby.

Source:  [Arrested Development wiki](http://arresteddevelopment.wikia.com/wiki/Beef_Consomm%C3%A9)